# Getting 405 - Method Not Allowed in Swagger (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I'm getting a 405 - Method Not Allowed error when testing a GET method in Postman. In a browser, when trying to use `swagger-ui` I'm getting a Whitelabel Error Page.

I'm on Java 17, Spring Boot 2.7.3, and I'm using Swagger 3.0.

Here's the Swagger configuration. I've had to remove `@Configuration` because Spring Boot couldn't start when that annotation was in use and `DocumentationType.OAS_30` is here instead of `SWAGGER_2` because I'm using Swagger 3.0.

```
package hr.ogcs.blueprint;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("hr.ogcs.blueprint"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }
}
```

Here's a Gradle configuration. I've tried with `springfox-boot-starter` dependency, but the Spring Boot couldn't start with it. So I added `swagger2` and `swagger-ui` dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does your application has defined a context path? If yes, then you have to include it when accessing swagger URIs.

Comment: Well it does: @RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
`public class GarageController {//some code}`
but I'm not getting anything when the path is included in the URL `http://localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui`

Comment: Did you try http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html ? Check for example this: https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/documenting-spring-boot-rest-api-swagger-springfox/ if you cannot set it to work.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that URL, too. I tried various dependency combinations (for Swagger 2.x, Swagger 3.0), but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

In order to solve this issue, I dropped the Springfox library and used another library named SpringDoc. The Springfox obviously still doesn't work with Swagger 3.0 so remove this from your Gradle:

```
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
```

The solution is quite simple.
Use this dependency instead, and everything will work like a charm:

```
`implementation` 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.11'
```

You don't need any additional Swagger Config file or any annotation. Now go to `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` to see the results.

I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation) on Baeldung.